# How to set the defaultRout in Yii2 to point to a module controller?

Tags: php, yii2

How can one set the defaultRoute in yii2 to point to a module controller instead of the site controller.

```
$config = [
   'defaultRoute' => 'app\modules\test\controllers\DefaultController',
'modules' => [
    'test' => [
        'class' => 'app\modules\test\Module',
    ],
],
```

I had set the path in the array above, however it gave me an error

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

the correct path is the modulename/controllername

```
'defaultRoute' => 'modulename/default',
```

thanks